# Weird class naming hiding the element

Tags: html, css

I have been studying CSS, however i came across a weird behavior, there is this anchor element that i gave a class with name "sponsor-link", it does not show up in Firefox nor in Chrome(completely removed from the DOM tree), however if i name it something else(i.e. sponsor-link-btn) then it shows up.

Can anyone explain why using "sponsor-link" as class name can remove an element?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Box</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Franklin Running Club</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <main class="main">
        <h2>Come join us!</h2>
        <p>
            The Franklin Running club meets at 6:00pm every Thursday
            at the town square. Runs are three to five miles, at your
            own pace.
        </p>
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <a href="/twitter" class="button-link">
            follow us on Twitter
        </a>
        <a href="/facebook" class="button-link">
            like us on Facebook
        </a>
        <a href="/sponsors" class="sponsor-link">
            become a sponsor
        </a>
    </aside>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*,
::before,
::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0072b0;
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

main {
    display: block;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.main {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.sidebar {
    width: calc(30% - 1.5em);
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.button-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0090C9;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button-link + .button-link {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.sponsor-link {
    display: block;
    color: #0072b0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: How is it even possible? Just look in your code you must have removing it from DOM, search for the classname in your whole project. As for me the code you have pasted here is working

Comment: I just figured, adblock blocked the element for simply have "sponsor-link" text. quite amusing.

Answer (score 1):

I found out now.

My browsers have AdBlock Plus plugins,
which hide the element.

I think ABP black listed the text "sponsor-link"